# Find string and create additional column

Tags: r

I have a list of data that contains a bunch off strings that contain currency codes.  The location of the code varies within the string, and I am looking for a way to separate the code out.

I've tried searching, but all the suggestions I can find centre around the string being in the same location or separated by a similar character (eg. _ or -)

My input looks something like this:

```
input = structure(list(V1 = c("asdf23.USD123", "DKK1234", "1dCNY_d", 
"fgdUSD33", "912#NZD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

and I have a list of currencies I'm looking for like this:

```
fx = c("CNY", "DKK", "NZD", "USD")
```

I am trying to search the V1 column for values that match the list, and create a new column with the corresponding currency, eg:

```
output = structure(list(V1 = c("asdf23.USD123", "DKK1234", "1dCNY_d", 
"fgdUSD33", "912#NZD"), V2 = c("USD", "DKK", "CNY", "USD", "NZD"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I don't know where I'd begin to look.  Can anyone suggest what I should be searching for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to extract the substring based on the value of 'fx' by `paste`ing the elements in to a single string

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
input %>% 
   mutate(V2 = str_extract(V1, str_c(fx, collapse="|")))
#             V1  V2
#1 asdf23.USD123 USD
#2       DKK1234 DKK
#3       1dCNY_d CNY
#4      fgdUSD33 USD
#5       912#NZD NZD
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
input$V2 <- regmatches(input$V1, regexpr(paste(fx, collapse="|"), input$V1))
```